# Post Pictures directly to Facebook using Facebook.dll in WP7

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to post a picture to photos section in facebook. I saw many examples but I could see that I have to pass the URL of the image to post it

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "Article Title";
parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
```

Is there any way to upload the picture instead of providing the URL link to the image.

Comment: it is necessary to upload the picture to a web server first, or can it be uploaded from the wp7 client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would have to upload the photo using the [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) or [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) APIs, and then reference it in a post via the [`object_Id`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: do you know if there is a full example somewhere?